# Using Dynamic fields/values in SUMIFS

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have one large DATA table that is refreshed from a SQL Server.

Example DATA table, 6 x string values and 5 x numeric values:

```
AREA | COUNTRY | CATEGORY | SALES GROUP | AAA | BBB | SALES $ | COSTS | VAL1 | VAL 2 | VAL 3
```

I have second, SUMMARY table with a number of columns that match field names in the DATA table.  These are broken down so you can see summary values at different levels:

```
BREAKDOWN                 | SALES $ | COSTS | VAL1 | VAL 2 | VAL 3

EUROPE                      SUMIFS | SUMIFS | SUMIFS|SUMIFS|SUMIFS
 - ENGLAND
 -  - SMALL BUSINESS
 -  -  - Joe Green
 -  -  - Molly Mongers
 -  -  - Patent Felicity
 -  - CORPORATE
 -  - MAJOR
 - FRANCE
 - GERMANY
 - AUSTRIA
```

I've got a SUMIFS statement which I want to make more dynamic so it references column names to retrieve different data:

```
=SUMIFS(qryDATA[COSTS],qryDATA[AREA],"Europe",qryDATA[COUNTRY], "France")
```

I can change the Criteria VALUES to be dynamic thus:

```
=SUMIFS(qryDATA[COSTS],qryDATA[AREA],D9,qryDATA[COUNTRY],'EXEC VIEW'!AC6)
```

But if I try the same with SUM field or CRITERIA FIELDS, I get an error (won't accept entry {There's a problem with this formula}).  `AD8` contains the text `COSTS`:

=SUMIFS("qryDATA[" & AD8 & "]",qryDATA[AREA],D9,qryDATA[COUNTRY],'EXEC VIEW'!AC6)

How can I get the sum field name (COSTS) from the 1st/2nd examples, to be a cell reference?

Thnx

Comment: What exactly are you asking. For COUNTIFS the column needs to be selected either using the heading like you are or the range (AD1:AD100). Selecting AD8 within column CMMTD_TOTAL makes no sense

Comment: I think he means that cell AD8 will contain a string such as "CCMMTD_TOTAL" so that the user could simply define the table field within one cell (AD8).

Comment: @JordanBiddlecombe correct, then I can copy the formula across and it will pick up each of the headers above the formula, pulling in the respective field names in the DATA table: SALES $ | COSTS | VAL1 | VAL 2 | VAL 3 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(qryDATA,0,MATCH(AD8,qryDATA[#Headers],0)),qryDATA[AREA],D9,qryDATA[COUNTRY],'EXEC VIEW'!AC6)
```

Comment: See, this is the kind of out of the box thinking I've come to expect from StackOverflow.  Perfect. Many thanks.